How to solve the error: status FAILED_PRECONDITION in Android Studio Gemini?
I want to try out the new Gemini assistant in Android studio. However it will not work due to an unexpected network error. It states:
Please try again later. Error: Status FAILED_PRECONDITION
I tried installing the most recent Android Studio versions and logging in with my Google account. Accepting the terms and conditions for Gemini and gave project permissions. After asking one of the suggested questions, I got an error instead of an answer.
Android Studio versions used:

Android Studio Koala 2024.1.1 (Build #AI-241.15989.150.2411.11948838, built on June 10, 2024)
Android Studio Koala Feature Drop 2024.1.2 Canary 8 (Build #AI-241.18034.62.2412.12022747, built on June 27, 2024)

Example:
Gemini start page
Error instead of answer

Same issue here...

I had the same problem, and I found this page from Google itself that helped: Troubleshooting guide.
This problem, FAILED_PRECONDITION, was defined "User location is not supported for the API use without a billing account linked.", and as a solution, "To use the Gemini API, you will need to setup a paid plan using Google AI Studio.". Basically, you can't use Gemini AI without having a paid account.
In this other webpage, Available regions for Google AI Studio and Gemini API you can verify whether your country is also required to have a paid plan (the ones with the blue 1 need paid plan)
Hope this helps, this is indeed the case for me. Now is time to try and avoid this regional barrier, good luck to y'all too ; ).

This seems to be the right answer. Unfortunately residents of my country need a billing account set up with the credit card payment method, which is not a common payment method here... Also I'm surprised that this isn't mentioned in the Android developers documentation.

I face the same problem ,i guess the reason may be:

Blockquote
Gemini in Android Studio is available in the following countries and territories:
Algeria
American Samoa
Angola
Anguilla

https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/gemini/availability

According to this availability list the Gemini assistant should work for me. But the error persists.
